# Никак не могу понять qt код.

Tags: qt, c++

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(2);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);

ui->tableWidget->setColumnWidth(1,12);

}
```

Я так понимаю, здесь происходит наследование конструктора базового классa QMainWindow. Вызывается два конструктора - тот что написан здесь, и тот же параметр передаётся конструктору QMainWindow, который тоже выполняется, так? а для чего тогда нужно `, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)`, что  это делает?

Answer (score 2):

Вызывает конструктор поля `ui` с параметром `new Ui::MainWindow`, разумеется.

Это не Qt-специфический код, это стандарт C++.

Answer (score 0):

это инициализация переменных класса.